# WooCommerce - Show regular price striked before the sale price in the add to cart button?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to show the regular price before the discounted price in the add to cart button on the single product pages only.

Here's the code snippet I added to the functions.php file of my child theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); 
function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
global $product; 
$regular_price = woocommerce_price( $_product->get_regular_price() );
$sale_price = woocommerce_price( $_product->get_sale_price() );
    return __( 'Add to cart' . $regular_price . $sale_price, 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```

This code is incorrect and crashes the website but I don't understand why. Can anyone help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The code crashes because you use a variable `$_product` which is not defined inside your hook. Please try this code instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text' );
function filter_woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text(): string {
    global $product;

    $regular_price = wc_price( $product->get_regular_price() );
    $sale_price    = wc_price( $product->get_sale_price() );

    return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) . $regular_price . $sale_price;
}
```

I've fixed your variable name `$_product` to `$product` (as defined inside a global) and moved your price to text assignment outside the translation function. Also, I've preplaced the deprecated function `woocommerce_price` with `wc_price`.

This way, your code works but don't display the price correctly since this filter filters only the text as a string.

I think you need to check for a different hook to achieve your goal.